# How to dynamically specify the collection name when creating a document with Mongoose create method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created a model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const flashcardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
});

const flashcard = mongoose.model('Database', flashcardSchema);
module.exports = flashcard;
```

'Database'- this arugment stand for a name of a collection in MongoDB, but i want to make it dynamic.
So i can modify it to:

```
 const collectioName= 'collection'
 const flashcard = mongoose.model(collectioName, flashcardSchema);
 module.exports = flashcard
```

but the problem is that i create and save flashcard by create() method:

```
   exports.createFlashcard = async (req, res, next) => 
    try {
        const newFlashcard= await Flashcard.create({})
```

and i have no acess to const collectioName.
Should I add 4th arugment to:

```
 exports.createFlashcard = async (req, res, next, collectionName) => 
        try {
            const newFlashcard= await Flashcard.create({})
```

and somehow pass it to create function? How to make it work?

it want it so i can call the createFlashcard(collectionName) from frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of mongoose is to infer the collection name from the first parameter of the `mongoose.model()` function. It looks for the pluralised, lowercase version of that parameter. So given the following model:

```js
const flashcard = mongoose.model('Flashcard', flashcardSchema);
```

mongoose will take `Flashcard` and look for a `flashcards` collection.

However, the function also takes an optional third parameter that is the explicit collection name and if present when the `mongoose.model` is called it will use that and override the default behaviour described above. This can also be parameterised with a variable like so:

```js
// req.body = {user:'bob', collection:'flashy'}
const dynamicName = verifyAndSanitizeFunction(req.body.collection);
const flashcard = mongoose.model('Flashcard', flashcardSchema, dynamicName);
```

This will now look for a collection named `flashy`. Just to be clear you can also just pass in a string:

```js
const flashcard = mongoose.model('Flashcard', flashcardSchema, 'flashy');
```

See [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.model()) for official API docs.

You can export a function that returns a `mongoose.model` which will allow you to pass the collection name in when you instantiate the model like so:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flashcardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    //...
})
const createModel = (collection) => {
    return mongoose.model("Flashcard", flashcardSchema, collection)
}
module.exports = {createModel};
```

You don't need a `exports.createFlashcard` function as it seems too overengineered. Just grab the collection name from the front-end and use that to create the Flashcard model like so:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const {createModel} = require('./models/Flashcard.js');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/flashcard/create", async (req, res) => {
    try{
       const dynamicName = verifyAndSanitizeFunction(req.body.collection);
        const Flashcard = createModel(dynamicName);
        const card = await Flashcard.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            //...
        });
        res.status(201).json({ card });
    } catch (err){
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});
```

If you really wanted to you could just import the `createModel` function into your `exports.createFlashcard` function and grab the collection name from that `req` object but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: thanks sir for time and answer; the problem is that const flashcard = mongoose.model('Flashcard', flashcardSchema, 'flashy') is in Model.js and 
 exports.createFlashcard = async (req, res, next, collectionName) => 
        try {
            const newFlashcard= await Flashcard.create({}) is in controller.js

Comment: Updated answer to show how you can accommodate that.

Comment: You're welcome. I just saw another question using flashcard schemas very similar to this  . Good luck with your project.

Comment: the similar question doesnt exist no more 